# How to read file from another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This script lists the unit-*-slides.txt files in from directory to a filelist.txt file and from that file list it goes to the file and reads the file and gives the count of st^ lines to a file.but it is not counting in order for ex 1,2,3,4,.... it is counting like 10,1,2,3,4......

How to read it in order.

```
#!/bin/sh
    #
    outputdir=filelist
    mk=$(mkdir $outputdir)
    $mk
    dest=$outputdir
    cfile=filelist.txt
    ofile="combine-slide.txt"

    output=file-list.txt
    path=/home/user/Desktop/script
    ls  $path/unit-*-slides.txt | sort -n -t '-' -k 2 > $dest/$cfile
    echo "Generating files list..."
    echo "Done"

    #Combining
    while IFS= read file
    do 
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        tabs=$(cat unit-*-slides.txt | grep "st^" | split -l 200)
        fi
    done < "$dest/$cfile"
    echo "Combining Done........!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sort -n`

```
tabs=$(cat $( ls unit-*-slides.txt | sort -n ) | grep "st^" | split -l 200)
```

`sort -n` means *numeric sort*, so output of `ls` is ordered by number.

Comment: or use `ls -v` for the "version" listing